# jquery table sorter and ajax

Tags: jquery

I have a table using a table sorter plugin that is getting drilled out from the database using php. Within the row, I have a jquery/ajax call that get fired on button click. I have no issues with the ajax or the table sorter working inddependently. However when I either sort a column or page through, the price updater(ajax) only with work within the first 7-10 rows of the table...I have tried a couple table sorter plugins and one just totally shuts down the ajax after a sort and this one only gives me a few row to work in...Any thoughts?

Comment: It's hard to know without knowing the: plugins involved and a sample page replicating the problem (hint: try using http://jsFiddle.net).

Comment: This is just a suggestion. try using jqGrid. It works really well with table data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using ajax request to load dynamic data, any of the existing events are not valid for the new elements. so after you load dynamic data, you need to call table sorter again. this will solve your problem

Comment: no the data is being drilled out by PHP just in a simple repeat region.

Comment: so then what you are trying to do with ajax

Comment: <table>
    <tr data-id="11">
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><button>go</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-id="23">
        <td><input type="text"></td>
        <td><button>go</button></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ... -->
</table>

$('table button').click(function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var id  = $tr.data('id');
    var val = $tr.find('input[type=text]').val();
    // ...Sends Ajax REquest for Price Update
});

Comment: so you are updating the table data(price). just call the table sorter again after ajax call

Comment: It is the ajax function that stops working after the table sort. For example when I sort by price the ajax function stops working. I can not call to it.

Comment: @GregBurris: change the code like this `$('table button').live('click',function() { var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'); var id = $tr.data('id'); var val = $tr.find('input[type=text]').val(); // ...Sends Ajax REquest for Price Update });`

Comment: if you are using jQuery 1.7+, you can use `on` instead of `live`